# Haskell: Parse error in pattern: a - 1 Possibly caused by a missing 'do'?

Tags: haskell, ghc

While trying to implement the famous [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) in Haskell to test whether the promised difference in running time is actually measurable, I stumbled across this beauty of an error description:

> ```
>    Parse error in pattern: a - 1 
>    Possibly caused by a missing 'do'?
> ```

I know that this parsing error is appearing pretty commonly and I have no idea why it does so.
Other than that, my code (see below) should be fine.

My code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
    print "Please enter first operand: "
    input <- getLine
    let n = read input
    print "Please enter second operand: "
    input <- getLine
    let m = read input
    let r = ak(n,m)
    print(n++" ackermann "++m++" = "++show r)



ak(a,b) = do
    if a == 0 
        then return (b+1)
    else if b == 0 
        then return ak(a-1, 1)
    else 
        s1 <- ak(a-1, b)
        s2 <- ak(a-1, s1)
        return s2
```

Comment: Don't use `do` and `return` for `ak`. `do` blocks are used for monadic computations...

Comment: You appear to be trying to guess Haskell's syntax without actually looking at existing Haskell code. The parentheses aren't part of Haskell's call syntax, and `<-` is not a general-purpose assignment operator.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `ack` grows very, very fast. Faster than any primitive recursive function. Faster than anything you can write using nested "for loops". You won't be able to compute it except for smallish values of its first parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `do` and `return` for `ak`. `do` blocks are used for *monadic* computations. You can work with:

```
ak 0 b = b + 1
ak a 0 = ak (a-1) 1
ak a b = ak (a-1) (ak a (b-1))
```

Then you can implement `main` as:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
    print "Please enter first operand: "
    n <- readLn
    print "Please enter second operand: "
    m <- readLn
    putStrLn (show n ++ " ackermann " ++ show m ++ " = " ++ show (ak n m))
```